# Auxiliar methods for rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise, has-one

I'm working with Devise and I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_one :address
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In one of my views you can find it:

```
Welcome <%= current_user.name %>
<% current_user.friends.each do |x| %>
<p><%= x.name + " " + x.address.data %></p>
<% end %>
```

Well, I don't know if the way of accessing to the data address is correct, but I would like do something like this:

Where get_address_data

```
def get_address
 this.address.data
end
```

But I don't find the correct way to do it works.